ESLint for TypeScript and Svelte: no-unused-vars Warning with Reactive Stores
I'm encountering a problem with my ESLint configuration when using Svelte and TypeScript. Despite following various guides, I keep getting no-unused-vars warnings for reactive statements. Here's my .eslintrc.cjs configuration:
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.svelte'],
      parser: 'svelte-eslint-parser',
      parserOptions: {
        parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      },
    },
  ],
  extends: [
    'plugin:svelte/recommended',
    'plugin:boundaries/recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:storybook/recommended',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    requireConfigFile: false,
    ecmaVersion: 2021,
    sourceType: 'module',
    extraFileExtensions: ['.svelte'],
  },
  plugins: ['boundaries', '@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    'no-inner-declarations': 'off',
    'svelte/no-at-html-tags': 'off',
    'no-self-assign': 'off',
    'svelte/no-unused-svelte-ignore': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    'react/jsx-key': 'off',
    'svelte/no-unknown-property': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': [
      'warn',
      {
        args: 'after-used',
        argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
        ignoreRestSiblings: true,
        varsIgnorePattern: '^_.*$',
      },
    ],
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['!**/mock*.js', 'dist', 'node_modules', 'mocks', '!.lintstagedrc.json'],
  settings: {
    'svelte/ignore-styles': () => true,
    'svelte/typescript': require('typescript'),
    'boundaries/elements': [
      {
        type: 'templates',
        pattern: 'example/**',
        mode: 'file',
        capture: ['category', 'elementName'],
      },
    ],
  },
};

Despite this, I'm getting the following warning:
import { store } from '@js/stores/globalStores';

$store = 'abc'; // Warning: 'store' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_.*$/u (@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)

Development Environment:
Svelte version: "4.2.17"
TypeScript version: "5.4.5"
ESLint version: "8.57.0"
typescript-eslint version: "7.1.0",
